# How do I change fill color of tasks from Ms Project -VBA given that I have the task IDs in an array?

Tags: vba, ms-project

How do I change the fill color of tasks from Ms Project -VBA given that I have the task IDs in an array? Currently I can only perform this to a single task.

```
Dim ID As Long
ID = 7

Application.Find Field:="ID", test:="equals", Value:=ID
Font32Ex CellColor:=&H66CCFF
```

Comment: which line is showing error ?

Comment: There is no error, I want to convert this code to ID() array, then it will give an error.

Comment: You can do a For loop from lbound(Id) to ubound(Id).

Comment: @SajW, consider putting this in an answer and accepting it to close the loop.